# Update d3.js Radar Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and want to know how to update the following chart: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsb2097/xeppz7L6/). It's a very huge code, so I'm lost about what to do next.

It only prints "here" in the console.

```
function update() {
    console.log("here");
    var json = [
        [
            {"axis":"A","value":0},
            {"axis":"B","value":0},
            {"axis":"C","value":0},
            {"axis":"D","value":0},
            {"axis":"E","value":0},
            {"axis":"F","value":0},
            {"axis":"G","value":0},
            {"axis":"H","value":0},
            {"axis":"I","value":0}
        ]
    ];
    drawRadarChart('#chart-radar', wMaior, wMaior);
};
```

Comment: If you change the line 27 with some other value then you can see the data change. But what is that you exactly want to do ?

Comment: That variable is the initial value loaded, I want to click a button and update the chart with new values.

Comment: click the `Run` at the top left side :) once you update the code

Comment: I mean the `<button id="update">Update</button>`.

Comment: The code that you want to do is already called, its the last line. There is a bug in the code, needs to be fixed. Another way to do it is after code changes click update on top of the page and then the page will automatically refresh thats the best i can suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is stored in the variable json, which you have already defined. You could save the new data in this variable and update the chart. Try changing your function update():

```
function update() {
    console.log("here");
    json = [
        [
            {"axis":"A","value":0},
            {"axis":"B","value":0},
            {"axis":"C","value":0},
            {"axis":"D","value":0},
            {"axis":"E","value":0},
            {"axis":"F","value":0},
            {"axis":"G","value":0},
            {"axis":"H","value":0},
            {"axis":"I","value":0}
        ]
    ];
    drawRadarChart('#chart-radar', wMaior, wMaior);
};
```

This way you get a new empty chart, as the values are 0.

Comment: Already changed to some other values, the problem is the chart is not updating with the new values!

Comment: Did you also change the 'var teiaJson' to 'json'? Have a look at the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dssw3w6q/) .

Comment: Got it, I was defining the variable again. Removed "var" and it worked. :D Thanks!